# Best way to let PHP access /dev/random?

Tags: php, owncloud

My OwnCloud installation is complaining about not having access to `/dev/random`. OwnCloud will request multiple random numbers from different sources and derive from these the final random number, and `/dev/random` is one of these sources.

Is adding `/dev/random` to open_base_dir a good idea? Ive read somewhere that it's not recommended. Is there a better way to solve this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem to add `dev/urandom` to open_base_dir and that will fix your ownCloud problem, but never add `dev/random` (without the u) as it can lack being fed enough entropy when generating the number.